# Is there any way to draw something on top of the root layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way to draw something on the top of my application **without extending or rearranging the already existing layout**?

Maybe there is a trick i don't know with the [Window](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html)

Think of it like Samsung's Galaxy Note Pen drawing that allows you to draw on top of existing application

I'm agnostic of the underlying layout. Also i don't want to distort it.

I know that probably there is not so please don't answer that there is not if you are not absolutely certain about it.

Comment: Do you mean draw by touching the screen with your finger or programmatically?

Comment: no need to touch but yes programmatically on an already given layout

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you need to use Canvas and/or Drawables.  Look here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: please revisit my question. I'm not asking how to draw. I'm asking how to draw on top of the screen without messing with the layout